# Preliminary System Introduction: Where to Start?

Tags: system-introduction, genesys

Genesys has been recommended to me as a system that *potentially* matches some of the things I've been looking for in RPG systems. I'd like to get a feel for it and do some sort of evaluation of its fitness for my needs before deciding whether to fully commit time and money to it.

Various systems and game lines have different preliminary introduction materials. ***GURPS*** has ***[GURPS Lite](http://www.sjgames.com/gurps/lite/)*** and used to have the ***All in a Night's Work*** CYOA (back in 3e as part of the ***Basic Set***). ***Exalted*** has a wonderful fanmade [interactive tutorial](https://mengtzu.github.io/exalted/sakuya.html). Various other systems have their own quick start and introduction kits.

What sort of Genesys material can I use to quickly acquaint myself with the basic principles and feel of the system to enable an informed choice about whether it's worth a deep dive?

Comment: I recommend looking at the Genesys Foundry on DrivethruRPG.com - though unfortunately I am insufficiently familiar with the available material to make a specific suggestion. Or, failing that, alternatively looking at FFG's Star Wars RPG Edge of Empire*. N.b. The star wars rpg is slightly different in a couple of ways, but is similar enough that you should be able to get a good feel for the system.

Comment: *The other two star wars core books are also similar, though the way Force works is particular to the Star Wars line, hence me suggesting Edge of Empire, though it is older, as it doesn't really deal with the Force - or at least, not to the same extent.

Answer (score 1):

### I could not find a tutorial one-shot for Genesys

The closest I game to was the Gencon one-shot [The Haunted City](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/56/75/5675bba2-a5a2-4161-b4c0-eaed85a3d0b7/genesys_gencon_adventure_lowres.pdf) which does not include rules.

### Consider an alternative

It's certainly not the same as trying, but there are YouTube videos with live gameplay that you could watch a couple of to get a feel for the system. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xQYhQHxyXKQ&feature=youtu.be) was recommended on a Reddit thread of the same subject, or you can find users' Playlists [such as this one](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLKVbhffQkYsWz1buK9m9jdKqQoieTnWUi).